# The effect of copying a refrence type into another one

Tags: python, data-structures, value-type

I have two classes as below:

```
class foo:
        def __init__(self):
            self.val = 10

class foo2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1000
```

When I copy an instance of class foo into a variable and then change a value of class foo, the variables changes. This is because the foo is a reference type and every change in foo changes its instances as well.

```
    f = foo()
    b = f 
    print(b.val)
    f.val = 20
    print(b.val)
    >> 10
    >> 20
```

But if I copy the class **foo2** into class **foo**, the variable **b** does not change to 1000. What is the explanation for this?

```
f = foo2()
print(f.val)
print(b.val)

>> 1000
>> 20
```

Comment: You haven't copied anything, you've assigned `f` to a new instance of a different class

Comment: https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: You didn't "copy the class foo2 into the class foo"; you made `f` point to an entirely different object. That doesn't affect the object previously referenced by `f` (and still referenced by `b`).

Comment: but b points to f and f points to foo. Now, if f points to foo2, be should point to foo2 as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why should `b` point to the instance of `foo2`? `b` doesn't point to `f`; `b` and `f` pointed to the same object. You just changed what `f` points to. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Python doesn't have a distinction between reference types and primitives, everything acts like a reference type. You would just say "object"

Comment: "b points to f" no, it doesn't. `b` and `f` happened to refer to the same object. Then you changed what `f` is referencing, but that doesn't affect `b`

Answer (score 0):

It's this line:

```
b = f
```

You haven't created a *copy* of the `f` object, you've created two different references to the same `f` object.  A change to either one will change both, because they're the *same* object.

Comment: I know but my question is when : f = foo2()